# Multiple Login Methods for single users table

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I am working on a Laravel application, we are very close to being done and the client suddenly wants us to implement some of the users to not have usernames and passwords, they want them to login with First Name, Last Name, and lasr 4 of there social, to make this work we also have a unique ID that will be provided in a link (for the rare case when 2 people have the same info)

We could split into multiple users tables, however that would require a major rework of almost the entire application as users is tied into it pretty tight

we have gotten the method to work, the problem is it breaks login for other users (including admins) who still will use username and password.

The first thing we have tried, is to try unsucessfuly to convince the client NOT to go with this route, but they have been hard set on it. Obviously we have tried to make routes so that a different login controller is used but with no luck, its always defaulting to loginController.

Standard login controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Standard;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class StandardLoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
    {
        if ($user->user_type == 'Patient'){
            if ($user->current_facility_id != null){
                return redirect()->route('patient.dashboard');
            }
        }

        return redirect('/home');
    }

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    //protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
}
```

Alternate login controller for new login method

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
    {
        if ($user->user_type == 'Patient'){
            if ($user->current_facility_id != null){
                return redirect()->route('patient.dashboard');
            }
        }

        return redirect('/home');
    }

    protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'linkID' => 'required|string',
            'firstname' => 'required',
            'lastname' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required|string',
        ]);
    }/**/

    public function username() {
        return 'linkID';
    }

    protected function credentials(Request $request)
    {
        return $request->only($this->username(), 'password', 'firstname', 'lastname');
    }
    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    //protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
}
```

routes from web.php

```
Route::view('standard-login', 'auth.standard.login');
Route::post('standard-login', 'Auth\Standard\StandardLoginController@login');
```

additionally some code from the users model

```
public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        if($this->user_type == 'Patient')
        {
            return $this->last4ssn;
        }
        return $this->password;
    }
```

ideally we will have two login portals
1. will use first name, last name, and last 4 of the social, and a unique id as a url parameter that is hidden (if no parameter, it can be typed in)
2. we will have a standard login using username and password

Comment: Possibly the auth middleware is redirecting to the default login page? Ensure it's disabled for the routes of the new login page.

Comment: we have two seperate login pages that show up fine, the problem is it is using the wrong login controller.

Comment: Then you're posting your login to the wrong URL. You did update the `action` attribute of the login form?

Comment: wow, can't belive i missed that, that was the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue has been resolved, turns out i did not update action on the login form and it was referencing the wrong login controller as a result.